# How to use MS Excel VBA to automatically enter data in Column A based on data in Column B?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to have an Excel sheet automatically enter a string in Column A when a name is entered in Column B.

I have it working exactly as intended in Google Sheets using this formula in Cell A1:

```cpp
={"P#";ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B), SWITCH(B2:B,"Alpha", "PX", "Bravo", "P1", "Charlie", "P7", "!!"), ""))}
```

But I don't see a simple way to do the same in Excel short of copy/pasting a slightly different (and large) nested-IF mess into each successive cell. I believe I should be able to have a script run whenever a cell in Column B is modified, but I've not used VBS before.

The below script seems to be close to what I need as it runs only when text is entered in Cell B2 or below, but it is only returning the default case.

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Column = 2 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False                'prevent endless loop
        On Error GoTo Finalize                          'resume events
        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, pName As String 'initialize variables
        LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get range
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            pName = Range("B" & i).Value
            Select Case pName
            Case pName = "Alpha", pName = "Bravo"
                Range("A" & i).Value = "P1"
            Case pName = "Charlie"
                Range("A" & i).Value = "P2"
            Case Else                                   'other values
                Range("A" & i).Value = "!!"
            End Select
        Next i
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Given the input: `Alpha, Charlie, Bravo, Xenon`

the expected output would be: `P1, P2, P1, !!`

but instead the output is: `!!, !!, !!, !!`

Any assistance/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the issue was my lack of familiarity with VBS.

I've corrected the syntax for the switch statement and it seems to work now:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Column = 2 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False                'prevent endless loop
        On Error GoTo Finalize                          'resume events
        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, pName As String 'initialize variables
        LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get range
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            pName = Range("B" & i).Value
            Select Case pName
            Case "Alpha", "Bravo":
                Range("A" & i).Value = "P1"
            Case "Charlie":
                Range("A" & i).Value = "P2"
            Case Else:                                   'other values
                Range("A" & i).Value = "!!"
            End Select
        Next i
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```